# Database restore issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore

Restoring a 2.8 TB backup on the same SQL Server 2014 SP1 takes long and it has been almost 6 hours but the progress is stuck at 0 percent. Also, its state is showing as Suspended and there is one wait type, `async_io_wait`.

Comment: We need few clarifications related to your post, 1. Are you restoring from shared source or local source? Is target drive local or SAN?

Comment: Hi Rajesh thank you for your reply and  I am restoring from local drive

Comment: Please share few information. 1. Execute DBCC LOGINFO and see how many VLF (Virtual Log Files) there are? 2. What's size of T-Log file? 3. What's Checkpoint interval? 4. What's SQL Server Service LogOn account? 5. What's disk RPM? 6. Are you restoring from same disk as target??

Answer (score 1):

Just check... 
Whether you have instant file initialization on
(Find the user/service on which SQL Server runs and find whether that user/service have rights to perform volume maintenance tasks.)